# print a line which has a digit repeated n times in the third field

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file with contents:

```
20120619112139,3,22222288100597,01,503352786544597,,W,ROAMER,,,,0,mme2
20120703112557,3,00000000000000,,503352786544021,,B,,8,2505,,U,
20120611171517,3,22222288100620,,503352786544620,11917676228846,B,ROAMER,8,2505,,U,
20120703112557,3,00000000000000,,503352786544021,,B,,8,2505,,U,
20120703112557,3,00000000000000,,503352786544021,,B,,8,2505,,U,
20120611171003,3,22222288100618,02,503352786544618,,W,ROAMER,8,2505,,0,
20120611171046,3,00000000000000,02,503352786544618,11917676228846,W,ROAMER,8,2505,,0,
20120611171101,3,22222288100618,02,503352786544618,11917676228846,W,ROAMER,8,2505,,0,
20120611171101,3,22222222222222,02,503352786544618,11917676228846,W,ROAMER,8,2505,,0,
```

I need to check if the third field of any line has one digit repeated all through 14 times, like:00000000000000 and print such lines to another file

I tried this code:

```
 awk '$3 ~ /[0-9]{14}/' myfile > output.txt
```

But this prints lines having "22222288100618" such values as well.

Also i tried:

```
for i in `cat myfile`
do 
if [ `echo $i | cut -d"," -f 3 | egrep "^[0-9]{14}$"` ];
then echo $i >> output.txt;
fi
done
```

This doesn't help as well.This also prints all the lines.

But I only need these lines in the output file.

```
20120703112557,3,00000000000000,,503352786544021,,B,,8,2505,,U,
20120703112557,3,00000000000000,,503352786544021,,B,,8,2505,,U,
20120703112557,3,00000000000000,,503352786544021,,B,,8,2505,,U,
20120611171046,3,00000000000000,02,503352786544618,11917676228846,W,ROAMER,8,2505,,0,
20120611171101,3,22222222222222,02,503352786544618,11917676228846,W,ROAMER,8,2505,,0,
```

Thanks in advance for any immediate help

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this can be done with awk but this should work:

```
perl -aF, -nle '$F[2]=~/(\d)\1{13}/&& print'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like `0{14}|1{14}...`.  Try this:

```
$ for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do re=$re${re:+|}$i{14}; done
$ awk -F, --posix \$3~/$re/ myfile
```

(`gawk` requires --posix to recognize the interval expression `{14}`. This may not be necessary with all `awk`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using **grep**:

```
grep -E "[0-9]+,[0-9]+,([0-9])\1{13}" myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

sed -n '/^[^,]+,[^,]+,([0-9])\1{13}/p' input_file